# Android button appears differently in different activities

Tags: android, button, themes

I've stumbled on a small, but a very annoying problem:

I am using one button style on two separate activities, which means I have the same button text properties. But for some unknown reason the weight of the button text is different (in one activity the text seems to be more bold-ish).

Could it be that the problem is caused by different themes that both activities are based on?

Edit: I found the reason (it is quite embarrasing :D ), and it had nothing to do with xml. The reason, why the button text appeared differently, was different fonts. While i was applying fonts, i simply overlooked that particular button.

Comment: is the button in an xml layout or are you creating it programmatically?

Comment: the buttons are implemented with xml

Comment: @aphelion u can make switch case for this case ......and u have need to ad sum other tasks which relate to button ex for spinner if u select item 1 then your button do this else another case your button do another activity ........... it may help u ....

Comment: can you post those XMLs and style?